# Access static files using a relative path in hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have gone through http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files

But it didn't help me out.

I have a file `a.js` in a static directory in the root of the project.

I have configured `relativePath` as glue configuration as `inert` plugin that is in the root directory of the project.

```
        plugins: {
            'vision': {},
            'inert': {
                routes: {
                    files: {
                        relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'static')
                    }
                }
            },
            'visionary': {
                engines: {
             // other plugins
```

I have a server route as follows:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/a.js',
    handler: {
        file : 'a.js'
    }
}
```

But when I try to access `http://localhost:3000/a.js`, it throws a 404 error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Registering the `inert` plugin is the right way and allows you to serve static files.

You've multiple options to serve your `a.js` file, like using a wildcard route parameter for a dynamic approach to serve various JS files. Within the `handler` you'd need to set the path to your JS directory and inert will search for the given `file` within that folder:

```
server.route({  
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/js/{file*}',
  handler: {
    directory: { 
      path: 'public/js'
    }
  }
})
```

You can also specify a static route to your JS file and serve it like this:

```
server.route({  
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/mylocaljavascript.js',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    // reply.file() expects the file path as parameter
    reply.file('../path/to/my/localjavascript.js')
  }
})
```

Hope that helps!

If you want more information about serving static files: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-serve-static-files-images-js-etc

Answer (score 1):

To serve a directory you need to set your routes like this:

```
{
 path: '/{param*}',
 method: 'GET',
 config: {
  handler: {
   directory: {
     path: path.resolve('directory_path')
   }
  }
 }
}
```

To serve a static file you can do in this way:

```
{
 path: '/your_path',
 method: 'GET',
 config: {
  handler: function(request, reply) {
   return reply.file('your_pfile_path');
  }
 }
}
```

Don't forget to add on your server.js file the inert require and to register it.

```
var Inert = require('inert');
server.register(Inert, () => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code for serve route to the following

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/a.js',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply.file(a.js');
    }
});
```